# SQL Server query with every row

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables, one contains a list of months, and the second contains sales data for these months. But for some months there is no sales, hence those rows are not created. i.e. table 1 contains January to December. table 2 contain jan with sales, feb with sales, but march has no sales, so this row not exists, april with sales.

My requirement is I needed out put of jan with sales, feb with sales, march with nosales, april with sales.

How can I build a query for this?

Comment: Readers much appreciate questions where an attempt of some sort has been made. Would you do that and edit into the question what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Team, table 1 and table 2 have lot of other rows and columns. I have to filter from rows and columns as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with LEFT OUTER JOIN as the following:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH, SUM(ISNULL(SALES, 0)) 
FROM 
    MONTHS AS M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SALES_TABLE AS S ON M.<PRIMARY KEY> = S.<FOREIGN KEY> 
GROUP BY 
    M.<PRIMARY KEY>
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for your reply. but table 1 and table 2 have lot of other rows and columns. I have to filter from rows and columns as well :)

Comment: This is my query, which am trying

Comment: select a.mcmskey,b.avalue from idmv_entry_simple a left outer join idmv_bw_current_links b
on a.mcMSKEY=b.MSKEY and a.mcEntryType='MX_ROLE' and b.ocname='MX_PRIVILEGE' order by mcMSKEY

Comment: That should be working. What is the problem with this query?

Answer (score 1):

If you use normal `JOIN`, row with no matching will be discarded.

What you want is `LEFT JOIN`, it will retains the row with no matched row in second table (you will have ouput like `FEB    null`)

Read more about `LEFT JOIN` here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for your reply. but table 1 and table 2 have lot of other rows and columns. I have to filter from rows and columns as well :)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? You do the same query with your current `JOIN`, but only one change is replace `JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`. Check that

Answer (score 1):

Use left outer join

```
table1 left outer join
table2 on table1.month = table2.month
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for your reply. but table 1 and table 2 have lot of other rows and columns. I have to filter from rows and columns as well :)

Comment: It depends on what you want in result, but you must consider the differences between INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN @jayakumar

Comment: Hi Hasan,  the if the result don't have that column, i have to replace with zero. i.e.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no sales then there won't be any id that matches months in sales hence no row will be displayed. If you want the row to appear anyway you have to use left join.

```
select *
from month m left join sales s on m.id_month = s.id_month
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for your reply. but table 1 and table 2 have lot of other rows and columns. I have to filter from rows and columns as well :)

Comment: yes, I know, I'm just posting this as an example cause I don't know your tables. But the only thing you have to do is change your query from "join" to "left join" in between yout month and sales table. Nothing else.